# Translate Makefile with docker command to windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker, makefile

I have a Makefile with a Docker command outputting the following:

```
docker run --network host -v ${PWD}/.env:/.env chat-server
```

I want to translate this to Windows, but as I'm aware the `${PWD}` bash argument can not be used in Windows, I found the equivalent to be `%cd%`.

Can this simply be replaced in the argument, or do I have to refactor the entire command?

```
docker run --network host -v ${%cd%}/.env:/.env chat-server
```

Comment: The braces are part of `${PWD}`; I guess you would try `host -v %cd%/.env:/.env`.

Comment: If you're using GNU make you can use the make variable `$(CURDIR)` instead, then it will work on all different platforms without platform-specific code.